# import PHP data into Google Spreadsheet (refresh automatically)

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I use a external webservice which allow me to download my data via php
(the link is a .php, the download file is a .csv)

I need to add this data to a Google Spreadsheet.
And then to refresh automatically (every hour if possible) to add new data from the PHP source to the Google Spreadsheet.

I can't modify the .php as its an external webservice.

So i need to write a Google Docs (Google drive now) script which get this data every hour from the PHP source.

Thanks a lot if you can help me

Answer (score -1):

Well, it seems that [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) may suit you perfectly. Do you know it?
I think it worths taking a look at the [turtorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles) and [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide).

If this is not the answer you were looking for, please clarify.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I'm looking at it.
but I don't find how to do it.
I was thinking what i want to do is something basic and that many people have already done some scripts that I can easily adapt with my limited knowledge on this matter

Comment: Well, you'd probably have to apply yourself a little on studying Apps Script. But it shouldn't be that hard once you get a grasp on it. You'll surely need to use UrlFetch and Spreadsheet APIs and possibly playing with javascript regex and DocsList API.